# Свойства кастомного контроллера

Tags: javafx

Пробую создать свой компонент для JavaFX. В этом компоненте есть 2 метода в которые передается `true` или `false` и в зависимости от этого меняется содержимое компоненты, но при импорте Jar файла в Scene Builder в блоке `Custom` есть только одно свойство и оно не доступно для редактирования.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
  Как можно разрешить редактирование данного свойства и добавлять туда свои?

### [GitHub](https://github.com/Bleser92/ShowPassword)

**Controller**

```
public class ShowPassword extends Control {


private final String DEF_STYLE_CLASS = "show-password";



public ShowPassword() {
    init();
}


private void init() {
    getStyleClass().setAll(DEF_STYLE_CLASS);
}


@Override
protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
    return new ShowPasswordSkin(this);
}


private BooleanProperty showing;


private BooleanProperty showVisisble;



public final void setShowing(boolean value){
    ShowingProperty().set(value);
}


public final void setShowVisisble(boolean value){
    ShowVisisbleProperty().set(value);
}



public final BooleanProperty ShowVisisbleProperty(){
    if (showVisisble==null){
        showVisisble = new BooleanPropertyBase() {
            @Override
            protected void invalidated() {
                final Boolean v = get();
                pseudoClassStateChanged(PSEUDO_CLASS_SHOW_VISIBLE,v);
            }

            @Override
            public Object getBean() {
                return ShowPassword.this;
            }

            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return "show-visible";
            }
        };
    }
    return showVisisble;
}


public final BooleanProperty ShowingProperty(){
    if (showing==null){
        showing = new BooleanPropertyBase() {
            @Override
            protected void invalidated() {
                final Boolean v = get();
                pseudoClassStateChanged(PSEUDO_CLASS_SHOWING,v);
            }

            @Override
            public Object getBean() {
                return ShowPassword.this;
            }

            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return "showing";
            }
        };
    }
    return showing;
}


public final boolean isShowing(){
    return showing == null?false:showing.get();
}



public final boolean isShowVisible(){
    return showVisisble == null?false:showVisisble.get();
}




@Override
public String getUserAgentStylesheet() {
    return ShowPassword.class.getResource("showpassword.css").toExternalForm();
}


private static final PseudoClass PSEUDO_CLASS_SHOWING =
        PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("showing");


private static final PseudoClass PSEUDO_CLASS_SHOW_VISIBLE =
        PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("show-visible");
}
```

**Skin**

```
public class ShowPasswordSkin extends SkinBase<ShowPassword> {

private Image lockImg = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/icon/lock.png"));
private Image unlockImg = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/icon/unlock.png"));
private GridPane container;
private StackPane stackField;
private ImageView leftImg;
private ImageView rightImg;
private TextField textField;
private PasswordField passwordField;


public ShowPasswordSkin(ShowPassword control) {
    super(control);

    container = new GridPane();
    stackField = new StackPane();
    leftImg = new ImageView();
    rightImg = new ImageView();
    textField = new TextField();
    rightImg.setPickOnBounds(true);
    passwordField = new PasswordField();
    container.setGridLinesVisible(true);
    RowConstraints row1 = new RowConstraints();
    RowConstraints row2 = new RowConstraints();
    RowConstraints row3 = new RowConstraints();
    ColumnConstraints col1 = new ColumnConstraints(38,38,38);
    ColumnConstraints col2 = new ColumnConstraints();
    ColumnConstraints col3 = new ColumnConstraints(38,38,38);
    container.getRowConstraints().addAll(row1,row2,row3);





    if (control.isShowVisible()){
        col2.setMinWidth(100);
        col2.setMaxWidth(9999);
        col2.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
        container.getColumnConstraints().addAll(col1,col2);
        container.add(leftImg,0,0);
        container.add(stackField,1,0);
    }else {
        col2.setMinWidth(100);
        col2.setMaxWidth(9999);
        col2.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);
        container.getColumnConstraints().addAll(col1,col2,col3);
        container.add(leftImg,0,0);
        container.add(stackField,1,0);
        container.add(rightImg,2,0);
    }
    leftImg.setImage(leftImage(control.isShowVisible()));
    stackField.getChildren().addAll(textField,passwordField);
    getChildren().add(container);

    rightImg.setOnMouseReleased(e -> mousePresed(control));

    rightImg.setImage(showStateChanget(false));
    control.ShowingProperty().addListener(((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        System.out.println(newValue);
        if (newValue.booleanValue() != oldValue.booleanValue()){
            rightImg.setImage(showStateChanget(newValue));
        }
    }));

}

private Image leftImage(boolean value) {
    InputStream imageStram;
    if (value){
        imageStram = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/icon/login.png");
    }else {
        imageStram = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/icon/key.png");
    }
    return new Image(imageStram);
}

private Image showStateChanget(boolean value) {
        fieldActive(textField,value);
        fieldActive(passwordField,!value);
    return value?unlockImg:lockImg;
}

private void fieldActive(TextField field,boolean value){
    field.setDisable(!value);
    field.setVisible(value);
    field.setOpacity(value?1:0);
}



private void mousePresed(ShowPassword showPassword){
    showPassword.setShowing(!showPassword.isShowing());
}

@Override
protected void layoutChildren(double contentX, double contentY, double contentWidth, double contentHeight) {
    ShowPassword showPassword = getSkinnable();
    showPassword.setLayoutY(contentY);
    showPassword.setLayoutX(contentX);
    container.setLayoutX(contentX);
    container.setLayoutY(contentY);
    container.resize(showPassword.getWidth(),showPassword.getHeight());


}


@Override
protected double computeMinWidth(double height, double topInset, double rightInset, double bottomInset, double leftInset) {
    return (leftImg.getFitWidth()+(getSkinnable().isShowVisible()?rightImg.getFitWidth():0))-(leftInset+rightInset);
}

@Override
protected double computeMinHeight(double width, double topInset, double rightInset, double bottomInset, double leftInset) {
    return (leftImg.getFitHeight()+(getSkinnable().isShowVisible()?rightImg.getFitHeight():0))-(topInset+bottomInset);
}

@Override
protected double computeMaxWidth(double height, double topInset, double rightInset, double bottomInset, double leftInset) {
    return 9999;
}

@Override
protected double computeMaxHeight(double width, double topInset, double rightInset, double bottomInset, double leftInset) {
    return 9999;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Свойство "Show visible" нередактируемо, т.к. не согласованы имена свойства\геттера\сеттера:

```
private BooleanProperty showVisisble;
public final boolean isShowVisible(){...}
public final void setShowVisisble(boolean value){...}
```

Свойство `showing` не добавилось автоматически из-за особенностей парсера SceneBuilder'а. Если заменить на:

```
private BooleanProperty showingA;
public final boolean isShowingA(){...}
public final void setShowingA(boolean value){...}
```

, то всё встанет на свои места.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]